# How to display date format in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs4.2

In my ExtJs application, date is displayed as `+041526-12-31T18:30:00.000Z`.

Here is my code:

```
var startDate = Ext.util.Format.date(record.raw.instrument.data.startDate,'m/d/Y');
Ext.getCmp('startDateCDS').setValue(startDate);
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
border: false,
items: [
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Maturity Date',
    id: 'maturityDateCDS',
    style: 'background-color:#424141;',
    labelStyle: 'padding-left:10px'
}
]
})
```

I want the date to be displayed in the format: m/d/Y.
Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help you to add the [extjs] flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [renderer](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display-cfg-renderer) config:

`renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y')`